# Tkinter GUI toplevel

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk

def topLevel():
    top=Toplevel()
    top.title("Listbox test")
    notiLabel = Label(text ="----test----", font=('Times', 20))
    notiLabel.pack()
    notiLabel.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=W)

    noti = Label(text ="----test----", font=('Times', 18))
    noti.pack()
    noti.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W)

    f = Label(text ="------test-----")
    f.pack()
    f.grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=W)
    fa = Label()
    fa.pack()
    fa.grid(row=3,column=1, sticky=W)


root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Listbox test")

s = tk.Label(text =">>>test<<<", font=(('Times'),20))
s.pack()
s.grid(row=2,column=0)


N = tk.Label(text =">>>test<<<")
N.pack()
N.grid(row=3,column=0)


LB = tk.Listbox(width=50, selectmode =SINGLE)
LB.pack()
LB.grid(row=4, column=0)


TI = tk.Button(text="b1", width =50, command=topLevel)
TI.pack()
TI.grid(row=5, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

When the program runs, after click the command button b1, the information and label in toplevel window still print on the lower level window, how to fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't use `widget.pack()` and then use `widget.grid(row=_row_, colum=_column_)`...

Comment: Hi @F3AR3DLEGEND, I added this widget.pack() because its not working. Even after I added, still not working. not sure how it works...

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify on which frame (the `Toplevel()`) to add the new widgets:

```
from Tkinter import *

def topLevel():
    top=Toplevel()
    top.title("Listbox test")
    notiLabel = Label(top, text ="----test----", font=('Times', 20))
    notiLabel.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=W)

    noti = Label(top, text ="----test----", font=('Times', 18))
    noti.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W)

    f = Label(top, text ="------test-----") # note the 'top' parameter
    # 'top' was your Toplevel widget
    f.grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=W)
    fa = Label(top)
    fa.grid(row=3,column=1, sticky=W)


root=Tk()
root.title("Listbox test")

s = Label(text =">>>test<<<", font=(('Times'),20))
s.grid(row=2,column=0)


N = Label(text =">>>test<<<")
N.grid(row=3,column=0)


LB = Listbox(width=50, selectmode =SINGLE)
LB.grid(row=4, column=0)


TI = Button(text="b1", width =50, command=topLevel)
TI.grid(row=5, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I also got rid of the usage of both `.pack()` and `.grid()`, and stuck to only `.grid()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved it, using [this reference](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/39554/how-to-opening-a-new-window-on-clicking-menu-item):

```
top=Toplevel()
notiLabel = Label(top, text ="----test----", font=('Times', 20))
```

Instead of:

```
top=Toplevel()
notiLabel = Label(text ="----test----", font=('Times', 20))
```

I had to declare "top" in the widget and declare root in root widget.